# how to copy command output in to a bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, web, interface

I am making a bash script that needs to know the web interface of the Linux server.

I know I can file the interface using the commands `IP a` or `ipconfig`

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:3c:20:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 80057sec preferred_lft 80057sec
    inet6 fe80::7888:1c1e:859a:5c75/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

in this example, the interface is `enp0s3`

of course in every server the interface will be different, so what can I do about it?

is there any way that I can copy this data automatically and set it as a variable
on the script?

thanks!

Comment: Hint: it is PURE text (so you should include it here already as TEXT, and not as SCREENSHOT). Also note that your question title is highly confusing. Aren't you simply asking: "how do I fetch/process the output of some command line tool using bash"?

Comment: The short answer is: Yes, you can. You can store the standard output of any command into a bash variable. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Host may have multiple network interfaces with multiple web servers running.

Comment: You can pipe the output of your command and use parsing commands such as grep or awk to filter out what you need, but since I don't know exactly what you need, I can't provide a working command for you.
ip a | awk -F':' '/enp1/ {print $2}'  
where enp1 is actually what you have to figure out that is unique to that interface so that you can filter out your outcome
If you find something that filters out uniquely this output then the command should become easier to find

Comment: hey i made the changes of the post thanks.

about  multiple network interfaces, I don't care I just need one of them (its for wireguard)

Comment: doesn't seem right that any interface would work though...

Answer (score 0):

so after a big research, i found a solution

I will use this command to copy the interface

```
ip a | grep -o -P '(?<=2: ).*(?=:)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to know the "web interface" of the server. By this, I presume you mean the interface on which the **Web Server** is running.  Let's assume that this is a standard web server, using the standard ports for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. So the first thing you need to know is: Is anything listening on those ports on **ANY** tcp interfaces? For this you need the `netstat` command:

```
netstat -na
```

You can then filter this output looking for specific patterns using `sed` or `grep`. For example:

```
netstat -na | sed -ne 's/^tcp[6 ]*[0-9]* *[0-9]* *\([0-9.:]*\):\(\(80\|443\)\) .*LISTEN *$/\1 \2/p'
```

The `sed` regular expression looks complex, but it's really not too bad (I can provide an explanation if you wish). It should give you output similar to:

```
0.0.0.0 443
0.0.0.0 80
```

For IPv4, `0.0.0.0` means **ALL** interfaces. You then have the IP address(es) of all interfaces that are listening for HTTP or HTTP requests, which you can match to the output of the `ip` or `ifconfig` commands.